# Add Expires headers

Tags: html, yslow, expires-header

```
Add Expires headers
There are 21 static components without a far-future expiration date.

    http://static.doers.lk/examples-offline.css
    http://static.doers.lk/kendo.common.min.css
    http://static.doers.lk/kendo.default.min.css
    http://static.doers.lk/style.css
    http://static.doers.lk/jquery.min.js
    http://static.doers.lk/kendo.web.min.js
    http://static.doers.lk/console.js
    http://static.doers.lk/sprite.png
    https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/safe_image.php?...
    https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/safe_image.php?...
    https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/safe_image.php?...
    https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/safe_image.php?...
    https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/safe_image.php?...
    https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/safe_image.php?...
    https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/safe_image.php?...
    https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/safe_image.php?...
    https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/safe_image.php?...
    https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/safe_image.php?...
    https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/safe_image.php?...
    https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/safe_image.php?...
    http://static.doers.lk/favicon.PNG
```

When testing the site using yahoo YSLOW it says above message. So I don't know how to add expire headers. Any help would be appreciated?

Comment: hope ther would be documenattion in their site

Comment: Google `php Add Expires headers`

Comment: I'm assuming that `static.doers.lk` is your own website?

Comment: yes i used that cookeeless sub domain to set static content

Comment: [Here's an explanation for the YSlow message](http://gtmetrix.com/add-expires-headers.html).

Comment: I am using windows hosting, So i am not able to add .htaccess file. There are any other option to set expiration time in HTML meta tag?

Comment: https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html?guccounter=1&guce_referrer=aHR0cDovL3lzbG93Lm9yZy8&guce_referrer_sig=AQAAAE9k1CHyQCp5gbb_ebWnhDf3zjTquUxYrAUnzng2QGU7cKTwcK3M_J0OhSGTImNREuADoXvHMKEvpuz6Q4pWpBTenH3PYO4D2wgoxQlBuoGajt4GZg74bnio8U2abiFb1aGLOZKjW_YgLufo3Jt8MhFChXScC9si-tOqsGPE942C#expires

Answer (score 74, accepted):

The easiest way to add these headers is a `.htaccess` file that adds some configuration to your server. If the assets are hosted on a server that you don't control, there's nothing you can do about it.

Note that some hosting providers will not let you use `.htaccess` files, so check their terms if it doesn't seem to work.

The HTML5Boilerplate project has an excellent `.htaccess` file that covers the necessary settings. See the relevant part of the file at their [Github repository](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/dac15682b35ad69f519205e1b82694d0cab189ca/.htaccess#L192)

These are the important bits

```
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Expires headers (for better cache control)
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# These are pretty far-future expires headers.
# They assume you control versioning with filename-based cache busting
# Additionally, consider that outdated proxies may miscache
# www.stevesouders.com/blog/2008/08/23/revving-filenames-dont-use-querystring/

# If you don't use filenames to version, lower the CSS and JS to something like
# "access plus 1 week".

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive on

# Your document html
  ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 0 seconds"

# Media: images, video, audio
  ExpiresByType audio/ogg "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType video/mp4 "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType video/ogg "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType video/webm "access plus 1 month"

# CSS and JavaScript
  ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
```

They have [documented what that file does](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/v4.0.2/doc/htaccess.md), the most important bit is that you need to rename your CSS and Javascript files whenever they change, because your visitor's browsers will not check them again for a year, once they are cached.

Comment: No, just the "Expires headers" section. Or even just the part that I pasted into my answer. Please make sure you understand fully what it does, especially why [cache busting](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/v4.0.2/doc/htaccess.md#cache-busting) is needed once you use this.

Comment: i have an another question .can you give me an answer for it ?

Comment: You'll note, however, that the HTML5-boilerplate `.htaccess` script suggests that it's preferable to put this info in `httpd.conf` because of the performance hit on Apache from `.htaccess` files.

Comment: However Google PageSpeed Insights still claims I have only 10 minutes expiration times on my ressources. I'm using the H5BP .htaccess along with GitHub Pages.

Comment: Your server needs to support .htaccess files. Github pages don't: `GitHub Pages does not support customer server configuration files such as .htaccess` https://help.github.com/articles/redirects-on-github-pages/

Comment: I am using windows hosting, So i am not able to add .htaccess file. There are any other option to set expiration time in HTML meta tag?

Answer (score 12):

try this solution and it is working fine for me

```
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(js|css|xml|gz)$">
    Header append Vary: Accept-Encoding
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/css text/plain text/xml text/x-js text/js 
</IfModule>

## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add them in your htaccess file or vhost configuration.

See here : http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_expires.html

But unless you own those domains .. they are our of your control.

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    # Enable expirations
    ExpiresActive On 

    # Default directive
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"

    # My favicon
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"

    # Images
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"

    # CSS
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"

    # Javascript
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET there is similar object, you can use Caching Portions in WebFormsUserControls in order to cache objects of a page for a period of time and save server resources. This is also known as fragment caching. 
If you include this code to top of your user control, a version of the control stored in the output cache for 150 seconds.
You can create your own control that would contain expire header for a specific resource you want.

```
<%@ OutputCache Duration="150" VaryByParam="None" %>
```

This article explain it completely: 
**[Caching Portions of an ASP.NET Page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-1.1/h30h475z(v=vs.71))**