# How to enable caching of Javascripts files (e.g. jQuery) and CSS files at client side (Browsers/CLI etc.)?

Tags: javascript, css, caching, browser

Is there a way to enforce the caching of JS (say jQuery) and CSS files on browsers for a particular domain (Same way, as we can store cookies at client side for a particular domain)?

As we know such files change rarely and their caching at client side browsers will boost page-rendering speed significantly!

Comment: Yes. this is a very common practice, and the browser generally does it for you, though it helps for you to have your server return proper headers for said files. javascript and css have nothing to do with this.

Comment: @KevinB - Thanks for your prompt reply. Can you pls mention the syntax to do it for caching a JS (say jQuery) and CSS?

Comment: That depends on what webserver you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most browsers will handle this automatically, and you don't really need to worry about it. That's why it's often a good idea to use common javascript libraries from a CDN instead of serving them your own version.

If you want more control over how caching is handled, you can send expires headers along with the content. The accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13972629/add-expires-headers) has some good information about how to do this using .htaccess. If your server doesn't support .htaccess files, you can still do it via code directly.

If you are explicitly setting expires headers, make sure you're done developing your site, *or* make sure to disable caching in the browser you're working on