# Add expires header to OpenShift Do It Yourself(DIY) cartidge

Tags: php, .htaccess, openshift

I have launched Openshift DIY cartidge to server static web contents(html/css/js/images). I want to add expires headers for the contents so that contents are cached for local retrieval.

I found https://forums.openshift.com/cache-static-files-served-by-openshifts-application, but am not able to find .htaccess in DIY cartidge.

Also [Add Expires headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13972629/add-expires-headers) was what I was looking for, but I can anyone help me find the file where these configurations should go in Openshift DIY cartidge?

Comment: you need to create the `.htacess` file

Comment: So, should I create in .htaccess file where by index.html is placed or any other configuration directory?

Comment: yes, that should work fine

Comment: Its not working. YSlow plugin still complains the css and js do not have expires header.