# varnish 4 x-cache miss

Tags: caching, varnish, varnish-4

Hi i try configure varnish 4 in ubuntu 12.04

here is my varnish config

sudo more /etc/default/varnish

```
# Configuration file for Varnish Cache.
#
# /etc/init.d/varnish expects the variables $DAEMON_OPTS, $NFILES and $MEMLOCK
# to be set from this shell script fragment.
#
# Note: If systemd is installed, this file is obsolete and ignored.  You will
# need to copy /lib/systemd/system/varnish.service to /etc/systemd/system/ and
# edit that file.

# Should we start varnishd at boot?  Set to "no" to disable.
START=yes

# Maximum number of open files (for ulimit -n)
NFILES=131072

# Maximum locked memory size (for ulimit -l)
# Used for locking the shared memory log in memory.  If you increase log size,
# you need to increase this number as well
MEMLOCK=82000

DAEMON_OPTS="-a :80 \
             -T localhost:6082 \
             -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
             -S /etc/varnish/secret \
             -s malloc,5G"
```

more /etc/varnish/default.vcl

```
#
# This is an example VCL file for Varnish.
#
# It does not do anything by default, delegating control to the
# builtin VCL. The builtin VCL is called when there is no explicit
# return statement.
#
# See the VCL chapters in the Users Guide at https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/
# and https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/VCLExamples for more examples.

# Marker to tell the VCL compiler that this VCL has been adapted to the
# new 4.0 format.
vcl 4.0;

# Default backend definition. Set this to point to your content server.
backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8080";
}

sub vcl_recv {

 # Only cache GET or HEAD requests. This makes sure the POST requests are always passed.
#  if (req.method != "GET" && req.method != "HEAD") {
#    return (pass);
#  }

 # Strip hash, server doesn't need it.
  if (req.url ~ "\#") {
    set req.url = regsub(req.url, "\#.*$", "");
  }


if (req.http.Cache-Control ~ "(?i)no-cache") {
 if (! (req.http.Via || req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)bot" || req.http.X-Purge)) {
# return(purge); # Couple this with restart in vcl_purge and X-Purge header to avoid loops
unset req.http.Cache-Control;
}
}





# removes all cookies named _ and google analistics, tracking, utma, utmb...)
set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "(^|(?<=; )) *_.=[^;]+;? *", "\1");
set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "utmctr=[^;]+(; )?", "");
  set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "utmcmd.=[^;]+(; )?", "");
  set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "utmccn.=[^;]+(; )?", "");

  # Are there cookies left with only spaces or that are empty?
  if (req.http.cookie ~ "^\s*$") {
    unset req.http.cookie;
  }

 # Large static files are delivered directly to the end-user without
  # waiting for Varnish to fully read the file first. Varnish 4 fully supports Streaming, so set do_stream in vcl_backend_response()
  if (req.url ~ "^[^?]*\.(mp[34]|rar|tar|tgz|gz|wav|zip|bz2|xz|7z|avi|mov|ogm|mpe?g|mk[av]|webm)(\?.*)?$") {
    unset req.http.Cookie;
    return (hash);
  }

# Remove all cookies for static files

if (req.url ~ "^[^?]*\.(bmp|mov|mp4|webm|avi|bz2|css|doc|eot|flv|gif|gz|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|less|pdf|png|rtf|swf|txt|woff|xml)(\?.*)?$") {
    unset req.http.Cookie;
    return (hash);
  }


    # Happens before we check if we have this in cache already.
    #
    # Typically you clean up the request here, removing cookies you don't need,
    # rewriting the request, etc.

 set req.http.Surrogate-Capability = "abc=ESI/1.0";

if (req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto == "https" ) {
        set req.http.X-Forwarded-Port = "443";
    } else {
        set req.http.X-Forwarded-Port = "80";
    }

}

sub vcl_backend_response {
    # Happens after we have read the response headers from the backend.
    #
    # Here you clean the response headers, removing silly Set-Cookie headers
    # and other mistakes your backend does.

if (beresp.http.Surrogate-Control ~ "ESI/1.0") {
        unset beresp.http.Surrogate-Control;
        set beresp.do_esi = true;
    }

# Enable cache for all static files
if (bereq.url ~ "^[^?]*\.(bmp|bz2|css|doc|eot|flv|gif|gz|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|less|mp[34]|pdf|png|rar|rtf|swf|tar|tgz|txt|wav|woff|xml|zip|webm)(\?.*)?$") {
    unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
  }

# Large static files are delivered directly to the end-user without
if (bereq.url ~ "^[^?]*\.(mp[34]|rar|tar|tgz|gz|wav|zip|bz2|xz|7z|avi|mov|ogm|mpe?g|mk[av]|webm)(\?.*)?$") {
    unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
    set beresp.do_stream = true; # Check memory usage it'll grow in fetch_chunksize blocks (128k by default) if the backend doesn't send a Content-Length header, s
o only enable it for big objects
    set beresp.do_gzip = false; # Don't try to compress it for storage
  }

if (bereq.http.Cookie ~ "(UserID|_session)") {
        set beresp.http.X-Cacheable = "NO:Got Session";
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
        return (deliver);

} elsif (beresp.ttl <= 0s) {
        # Varnish determined the object was not cacheable
        set beresp.http.X-Cacheable = "NO:Not Cacheable";

} elsif (beresp.http.set-cookie) {
        # You don't wish to cache content for logged in users
        set beresp.http.X-Cacheable = "NO:Set-Cookie";
        set beresp.uncacheable = true; return (deliver);
        return (deliver);

} elsif (beresp.http.Cache-Control ~ "private") {
        # You are respecting the Cache-Control=private header from the backend
        set beresp.http.X-Cacheable = "NO:Cache-Control=private";
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;

} else {
        # Varnish determined the object was cacheable
        set beresp.http.X-Cacheable = "YES";
    }
        return (deliver);
}

sub vcl_deliver {
    # Happens when we have all the pieces we need, and are about to send the
    # response to the client.
    #
    # You can do accounting or modifying the final object here.

if (obj.hits > 0) { # Add debug header to see if it's a HIT/MISS and the number of hits, disable when not needed
    set resp.http.X-Cache = "HIT";
  } else {
    set resp.http.X-Cache = "MISS";
  }

set resp.http.XH = obj.hits;

unset resp.http.X-Varnish;
unset resp.http.Via;

}
```

i look on image caching

Response Headers

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Age:115
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:2703
Content-Type:image/jpeg
Date:Sat, 21 Nov 2015 09:59:42 GMT
ETag:"a8f-523e3697bdc69"
Last-Modified:Fri, 06 Nov 2015 18:28:37 GMT
Server:Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
X-Cache:HIT
X-Cacheable:YES
XH:7
```

Request Headers
(i disable cache in browser, varnish should ignore it )

```
GET /media/cache/mini_thumb/images/nofoto.jpg HTTP/1.1
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Accept: image/webp,image/*,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.86 Safari/537.36
   Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: pl-PL,pl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,pt;q=0.2,de;q=0.2,sk;q=0.2
```

When i refresh page in other browser i get response headers :

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 21 Nov 2015 10:11:36 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
Last-Modified: Fri, 06 Nov 2015 18:28:37 GMT
ETag: "a8f-523e3697bdc69"
Content-Length: 2703
Content-Type: image/jpeg
X-Cacheable: YES
Age: 0
X-Cache: MISS
XH: 0
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Connection: keep-alive
```

What could be the reason

X-Cache: MISS
XH: 0

Comment: Any progress here?  It's definitely worthwhile to check the `Vary` header of the response, as I wrote below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in headers is lack of Expires tag - when is added, varnish start caching.

Comment: added [Add Expires headers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13972671/3898339) still no luck. Is this post contains correct way to add header using .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

It's worthwhile to check if your backend is returning a `Vary` header.  If, for example, it was returning `Vary: Accept-Language`, then even subtle differences in the `Accept-Language` string of the request would result in a cache miss. See [Varnish docs](https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/users-guide/increasing-your-hitrate.html#http-vary) on the topic.